# has and is functions of jquery with datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working with jquery datepicker I've four fields and I want to apply next date in first two fields and in second two fields I want current date but its is not working as per my condition or something is wrong with my condition. here is my `jquery` code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //if($(".datepicker").hasId("field1") || $(".datepicker").hasId("field2")) {
        //if($(".datepicker").is("field1") || $(".datepicker").is("field2"))
        if(($(".datepicker").has("#field1") && $(".datepicker").prop("id") == "field1") || ($(".datepicker").has("#field2") && $(".datepicker").prop("id") == "field2")) {
            var today = new Date();
            var tomorrow = new Date();
            tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({minDate: tomorrow});
        } else {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({startDate: new Date()});
        }
    });
```

and here is my `HTML` code

```
<input type="text" name="field2" id="field1" class="datepicker">
    <input type="text" name="field1" id="field2" class="datepicker">
    <input type="text" name="field3" id="field3" class="datepicker">
    <input type="text" name="field4" id="field4" class="datepicker">
```

I tried that in my project but not working then I start working at this sample code it is also not working and I also tried `is` and `hasId` function but not work for me what is wrong in my condition. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude `field1` and `field2`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Exclude field1 and field2
    $(".datepicker:not('#field1,#field2')").datepicker({startDate: new Date()}); 

    var today = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);      
    $("#field1,#field2").datepicker({minDate: tomorrow});            
});
```

Comment: on `field1` and `field2` I wanna show next day and block previous dates but at `field3` and `field4` I want to show previous and next date, my `field3` and `field4` are not showing datepicker.

Comment: Thank you Satpal.